# ¿Cómo contar el número de caracteres de una cadena según su tipo? (dígitos, letras, ...)

Tags: c++

Me gustaría saber el fallo que tengo en el código. La función es contar el numero de dígitos (inclusive los espacios) de un string. Por ejemplo si el string es: hola, debería devolver 4. El fallo es que me devuelve 0 la función.

Os dejo el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
int digitos(string cad){
    int count=0,s=cad.size();
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
        if(isdigit(cad[i])){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(){
    string cad;
    cout <<"Cadena: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,cad);
    cout<<digitos(cad)<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Al contrario: a nosotros nos falta saber el fallo que tienes. ¿Por qué dices que no funciona? ¿Qué error sale?

Comment: El título dice `dígitos`, pero en tu pregunta dices `si el string es: hola, deberia devolver 4`. ¿ Dígitos o letras ? `hola` no tiene ningún dígito.

Comment: Mi intencion es contar digitos y letras pero no se como.

Comment: si cuentas con isdigit, es complicado que hola retorne algo que no sea cero. El programa está haciendo lo que le dices que haga. Cambia el conteo con algo que no sea isdigit

Comment: ¿ Contando los espacios en blanco o sin contarlos ? ¿ Y los signos de puntuación ? ¿ Y los caracteres *raros*, como la `ñ` o letras acentuadas ? Y todos estos te darán problemas.

Comment: Qué has probado para hacer que cuente algo más que caracteres numéricos?

Comment: [Aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) tienes una guía con las funciones relacionadas y lo que cuenta/no cuenta cada una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hola veo que estas iniciando en la programación, lo único que tienes que hacer es seguir preguntando en tu for si hay espacios o letras o números...

```
int main() {
 string cad="Prueba 12";
int count=0,s=cad.size();
int alphabet =0;
int _spaces=0;

for(int i=0;i<s;i++){

    if(isdigit(cad[i])){
        count++;
    }
    if (isalpha(cad[i]) != 0) 
        alphabet++; 
    if (isspace(cad[i]) != 0) 
        _spaces++; 

}
cout<<"Digitos en la Cadena: "<<count<<endl;
cout<<"letras en la cadena: "<<alphabet<<endl;
cout<<"Espacios en la cadena: "<<_spaces<<endl;    

return 0;
}
```

creo resolverá tu duda?
[Prueba corriendo](https://repl.it/@gregdorian/contar-el-numero-de-digitos-de-una-cadena#main.cpp)